# How to force Perl use /bin/ksh instead of /bin/sh?

Tags: shell, perl, solaris-10

I am migrating from AIX to Solaris 10, but the version of `/bin/sh` there is so old, that our scripts does not work. Can I somehow force perl to execute commands in `` via different shell (in my case, `/bin/ksh`)?

I have A LOT of places with system calls, so changing them in every place is not very feasible. It would be great to find some global setting or something.

Comment: **if you configure your user profile to use it, i dont see why not.**

Comment: Profile always points to /bin/ksh

# echo $SHELL

/bin/ksh

Comment: Are you using these with cron or something ? that is the only way for it to actually not recognize the shell if you have changed it to something else. if that is the case the best you could do, is define the path to it within perl so it knows what to use instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a POSIX environment on Solaris, you need to put the standard conformance directory (`/usr/xpg6/bin`, the number can be different in different Solaris versions) early in your `PATH`, before `/usr/bin` or `/bin`. There is a POSIX-conforming `sh` in there (it's `ksh`, in fact), and a few utilities react differently depending on `$PATH` even though they come in a single executable.

Either hard-code the directories:

```
my @xpg_dirs = glob('/usr/xpg[0-9]/bin /usr/xpg[0-9][0-9]/bin');
$ENV{PATH} = "$xpg_dirs[@xpg_dirs-1]:$ENV{PATH}" if @xpg_dirs;
```

or impose a standard `PATH` with `getconf` (which oddly enough isn't in the `POSIX` module):

```
$ENV{PATH} = `getconf PATH`;
chomp($ENV{PATH});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374082/perl-backticks-use-bash-instead-of-sh) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've updated the question. Changing whole codebase is not a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shebang like this

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

add/repalce the above at the first line of script. It uses the /bin/ksh to execute the script.

Comment: This is alrady done, but script gets executed by sh. This is deadly strange.

Answer (score 0):

A thought that may help:

Can you update /bin/sh to the same version that was on your old AIX server where these previously worked. The perl behavior has not changed, just your version of /bin/sh

Comment: No, anything beyond user-level priveleges is extremely painful. :-)